# jqplot replot and recalibrate axis and ranges

Tags: refresh, jqplot

How do you get the jqplot to resize the min and max and ranges like it would on an inital plot? 
Right now it replots but the new data goes off the screen.

```
<body>
<input type=button onClick=replot() value=replot><br>
    <div id="chart1" style="height:400px;width:600px; "></div>

</body>

</html>

<script>
var plot1;
function replot(){
alert(plot1);
alert(plot1.data);
plot1.series[0].data=[[0,1],[0,2],[1,4]];
alert(plot1.data);
plot1.replot(); 
}

  // Some simple loops to build up data arrays.
  var cosPoints = [];
  for (var i=0; i<2*Math.PI; i+=0.4){
    cosPoints.push([i, Math.cos(i)]);
  }



$(document).ready(function(){
  plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [cosPoints], {
      title: 'Google, Inc.'
       });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

after some investigation I found the following fix

```
plot1.replot( { resetAxes: true } );
```

Now it works.